# Cannot install logpy package in python3.5

Tags: python-3.x, pip, package, pycharm

I was trying to install LogPy package in python3.5 but when I use the `pip install logpy` it backs me the following message:

> Collecting LogPy
>     Using cached LogPy-1.0.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File ".\Temp\pycharm-packaging\LogPy\setup.py", line 6, in 
>           long_description = open('README.rst').read(),
>       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'
>   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in .\Temp\pycharm-packaging\LogPy

Instead, I used the link [logpy](https://github.com/logpy/logpy) to install it locally. I've tried `pip3.5 install -e .\logpy-master\logpy-master` which didn't work and even used `python setup.py install`which didn't work too (it just installs kanren. it's not possible to use import logpy which returns an error).

So, what should I do?

P.S: I've searched a lot over it and the only one I've found who had the similar problem like me was [this](https://github.com/MHordecki/LogPy/issues/2). And non of

Answer (score 1):

You must use `pip install logic` so you can available logpy

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/logpy/logpy is **not** the package you want when you `pip install logpy`. And the installation package at [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/packages/b7/58/53ce8f101c036dd848f86fe6ebedcd849aa4802e1cfc5f613a31f7e93852/LogPy-1.0.tar.gz) is broken — it lacks `README.rst` required by `setup.py`.

Install LogPy from GitHub:

```
pip install 'git+https://github.com/MHordecki/LogPy#egg=logPy'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's like the original LogPy now exists under the name of Kanren or whatever this Kanren bears the methods more powerful than logpy under the name of logpy as I brought in my question. (https://github.com/logpy/logpy)